# Reboot remote Ubuntu computer with Python doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

Before you say this is a duplicate, I've tried every command I can find and I can't remotely reboot an Ubuntu 18.04 Linux computer via Python 3.6.

Commands I've tried:

```
import subprocess

cp = subprocess.run(['sudo', 'shutdown', '-f', '-r', '-t', '2'])
cp = subprocess.run(['sudo', 'shutdown', '-f', '-r', 'now'])
cp = subprocess.run(['sudo', 'shutdown', '-r', 'now'])
subprocess.Popen('using all the above commands...')
os.system('using all the above commands')
os.system('shutdown -r -t 1 -f')
os.system('shutdown /r /t 1')

stdout = subprocess.check_output(['sudo', 'shutdown', '-r', 'now'], shell=True)
```

That last command, using check_output(shell=True) returns the following stdout:

```
Command '['sudo', 'shutdown', '-r', 'now']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

My computer is remotely listening for commands via MQTT (Paho library). It successfully receives these commands and says that it's trying to execute them. No errors are reported, and the remote computer keeps running as though no command were issued at all. There is nothing in the stdout either (it just reports '' or 'None').

If I am in a terminal, I can easily reboot this computer with:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Why doesn't it work with Python? I've been using the subprocess.run(), subprocess.Popen(), and subprocess.check_output() methods for a long time now, and I'm very experienced with them. Other commands using those methods work just fine. I just can't reboot the computer remotely!

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: Is a password required for sudo?

Comment: @Keith, no, the password is not required. Good question

Comment: Still not clear to me where these are being run. If you do that from a local root shell, but from Python, does it work then?

Comment: @Keith yes. I launched python3 and ran "subprocess.run(['shutdown','-r','now'])" locally, and it rebooted. This computer subscribes to an MQTT topic (IoT pub/sub thing) and listens for commands. When a command like 'shutdown -r now' is received, the Python3 program subscribing to that 'topic' tries to run "subprocess.run(['shutdown','-r','now'])" and nothing happens...

Comment: Ah, that's going to be tricky since the service handling the command is going to be stopped. Try shutting down a short time in the future. Try looking at system log files for more clues.